# Find the exact value of $\tan⁡(\cos^{-1} (-\sqrt{3}/2))$.

Tags: trigonometry

The question: Find the exact value of $\tan⁡(\cos^{-1} (-\sqrt{3}/2))$.

[image]

The link is the image of the method I used. However it isn't the right answer, how come this method doesn't work?

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: Opposite side is $\sqrt{2^2-(\sqrt3)^2}=1$.  not $\sqrt7$. also note that the tangent is negative in second quadrant.

Comment: Please read our guidelines for [formatting and writing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) your question, including: "The key parts of your question should not be in an embedded image such as a photo/screenshot/etc., such images are not searchable, they are not accessible to those using screen readers, and they don't show up in question summaries."

Answer (score 1):

Use the famous identity $$\tan(\arccos(x)) = \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$$ I think you can take it from your here. You can check the answer after you have done it. The answer is : $$\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your work is with your evaluation of the length of the vertical leg:

$\sqrt{2^2-(-\sqrt3)^2}=\sqrt{4-3}=\sqrt1=1$

This leads to the correct answer of $\tan\theta=\frac1{-\sqrt3}=-\frac{\sqrt3}3 $.

Also keep in mind that your assumption that the angle is in the second quadrant is not warranted, since cosine is also negative in the third quadrant.  In that case, since tangent is positive in the third quadrant, that would lead to an answer of $+\frac{\sqrt3}3$.

Comment: The second-quadrant assumption is valid $-$ the inverse cosine function is, [by convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values), defined to take values in $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score -1):

Follow :

$$ \tan (\arccos(- \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}))$$

Suppose $x = \arccos(- \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$ :

$$ \cos x = - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \frac {\text{Adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$$

Pythagorean theorem:
$$\text{opposite side} = \pm~\sqrt{4-3} = \pm 1$$

$$ \tan x = \frac {\text{Opposite}}{\text{Adjacent}} =  \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} $$

**Considering $ 0 \le x \le \pi$ . Take only negative as $\tan$ is negative in second quadrant** :

$$- \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: Answer is not positive since $\tan$ is negative in 2nd quadrant

Comment: Hey, tan is positive in 3rd quadrant. That is also a possibility.

Comment: The common convention is that the range of the $\cos^{-1}$ function is $[0, \pi]$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values FWIW, the C standard library uses that convention, so it's widely used in programming languages related to C, &/or which use libraries written in C.

Comment: @Gaurang But, we are working in 2nd quadrant

Comment: That’s not mentioned in the Q @Algebrology

Comment: @Gaurang Look at the attached picture